# Flask Form not validating

Tags: python, validation, web, flask, web-applications

My Flask form isn't validating, I've tried changing things to look like the flask documentation example, but I can't figure out whats not working. Here's my code:

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, validators
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class PostForm(FlaskForm):
body = StringField('Body', [validators.Length(min=1, max=1000)])
post_title = StringField('Post Title', [validators.Length(min=1, max=1000)])
post_genre = StringField('Post Genre', [validators.Length(min=1, max=1000)])
submit = SubmitField('Submit Post')
```

models.py

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(20000))
    post_genre = db.Column(db.String(150))
    post_title = db.Column(db.String(300))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/editor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def editor():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        form = PostForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            flash('HELLOOOOOO')
            post = Post(post_title=form.post_title.data, post_genre=form.post_genre.data, body=form.body.data, user_id=current_user)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            return(redirect(url_for('login')))
        return render_template('editor.html', form=form)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Jinja/HTML

_formhelpers.html

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

editor.html

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

        <form method=post>
          <dl>
            {{ render_field(form.post_title) }}
            {{ render_field(form.post_genre) }}
            {{ render_field(form.body) }}
          </dl>
          <p><input type=submit value=Post>
        </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not showing the `LoginForm` class anywhere in your forms.py. We need to see it to help you

Comment: Made a typo, thanks for catching it. I put in the relevant class

Comment: What's your HTML? What data are you posting?

Comment: You need to post your html and the error info

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages, and I know the form isn't validating because when I click the submit button I don't get my sample flashed message and there is no redirect

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely running afoul of cross-site request forgery (CSRF) protection. In this case, a safe guess is that need to add

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

to the HTML form. See [the Flask-WTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/csrf.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

in your form you need to have `action` specified. That is the url it is sending a post request to. Because if you have `type="submit"` on a button inside a form, the  onclick event on the button is looking for that action attribute.

`<form method="post" action="/editor">`